# Using string class member functions

Tags: c++

Here's my task and below is most of the code I already wrote:

> Develop the program so that it finds and extracts specified items from the xmlstring file using start and end tags. Now we find and extract and display first the location information and then the temperature information.
>
> Location can be found between the tags `<location>` and `</location>`. The temperature is between the tags `<temp_c>` and `</temp_c>`.
>
> To make it easy to find whatever information from the, xml-string write a function that takes the xml-string and the "inner" text (same for start tag and end tag) of the tags as parameters and returns the text from between the start tag and end tags. If either start or end tag is not found the function must return "not found".
>
> Note that when you search for the tag you must search for the whole tag (including angle brackets) not just the tag name that was given as parameter.
>
> For example, if you wanted to find the location

```
location = find_field(page, "location");
```

> and to get the temperature you could call it as follows:

```
temperature = find_field(page, "temp_c");
```

MY CODE:

```
#pragma warning (disable:4996)

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

string find_field(const string& xml, string tag_name);


int main() {
    string page, line, location, temperature;
    ifstream inputFile("weather.xml");
    
    while (getline(inputFile, line)) {
        page.append(line);
        line.erase();
    }
    
    location = find_field(page, "location");    
    temperature = find_field(page, "<temp_c>");

    cout << "Location: " << location << endl;
    cout << "Temperature: " << temperature << endl;    
   
}


string find_field(const string& xml, string tag_name)

{
    string start_tag = "<" + tag_name + ">";
    string end_tag = "<" + tag_name + ">";

    return "not found";
}
```

SPECIFIC QUESTION

When I run the program it says:

```
Location: not found
Temperature: not found
```

Just not found. But it doesnt show the data that is in the file. How can I fix it? Thanks

Comment: Your `find_field()` does nothing else than `return "not found";`. The `start_tag` and `end_tag` should be complained by the compiler as unused local variables. So, what do you exactly expect? Your program does precisely what you told it to do. Btw. XML is a complex format which should be at best parsed with a resp. library. There are some of them available as Open Source, e.g. libXml2 or xercescpp.

Comment: _How can I fix it?_ There is not much to fix. (Code which is not yet written can not yet be fixed, you know?) ;-)

Comment: O.T.: `string end_tag = "<" + tag_name + ">";`: Shouldn't this be `string end_tag = "</" + tag_name + ">";`? `temperature = find_field(page, "<temp_c>");`: Shouldn't this be `temperature = find_field(page, "temp_c");`?

Comment: Hint: you might want to use the [`find`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find/) function.

Comment: Please do not delete questions. Leave them up and refer to them OR edit them

Answer (score 0):

I will not solve this completely for you, because I assume this is a task for you to actually learn, but I will give you some guidance.

In C++ you work on strings with iterators or offsets (positions). Since you are starting, I would suggest to first get familiar with offsets.

Basically, you need to search for the positions of `start_tag` and `end_tag` in your `xml` string and then return what is in between. The `std::string` class has a `find` method (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find/). You use it to find the start position of the search string. Additionally, you will probably need the `length` method (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/length/) for position calculation and the `substr` method (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/substr/) to get the interesting part.

Your pseudo logic of the find could be:

1. Find the start position of the `start_tag` in `xml`
2. Calculate the end position of the `start_tag` (start position + length of `start_tag`)
3. Find the start position of the `end_tag` in `xml`
4. Return sub-string between the two positions (the length is the difference between start position of `end_tag` and end position of `start_tag`)

Of course you need to check if the positions are valid before step 4 and if not return the `"Not found"`.

Additionally, please consider Scheff's third comment on your question, that the `end_tag` starts with `</` and that you need to call `find_field` without the angle brackets around your search string because you add them later in the function.

I hope this helps you find a solution.

Here is a very incomplete starter example:

```
string find_field(const string& xml, string tag_name)
{
    std::string start_tag = "<" + tag_name + ">";
    std::string end_tag = "</" + tag_name + ">";

    size_t start_tag_start_pos = xml.find(start_tag);
    // make some sanity checks to the position here (find returns std::string::npos if start_tag wasn't found)
    size_t start_pos_of_interesting_string = start_tag_start_pos + start_tag.length();

    // you can find the start_pos of the end tag similarly
    // don't forget sanity checks
    // calculate the length of between start and end tag

    return xml.substr(start_pos_of_interesting_string, /* you need to add the length of the interesting string here*/);
}
```

Comment: @ Rene Oschmann. Thanks. Can you explain me with some example code? I will appreciate it. Thanks

Comment: That is exactly what I wanted you to figure out yourself, but for start I will add some example (not complete)

Comment: @ Rene Oschmann. Is this ok for the start_pos of the end tag:  size_t end_tag_start_pos = xml.find(end_tag);
 
 size_t start_pos_of_interesting_string = start_tag_start_pos + start_tag.length();

Comment: yes, `size_t end_tag_start_pos = xml.find(end_tag);` is correct to find the start position of the end-tag